# Is there a general and completely automated (i.e. programmed) solution to modelling and forecasting time series data?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting

Is there a general and completely automated solution to modelling and forecasting time series data?

I think this question is extremely important.

If it is not possible, please provide an explanation why it isn't.

---

I'm interested to know whether anyone has completely automated the process of model building and forecasting in a way that works and allows a machine or programme do so without intervention.   I'm not so interested in whether a human can improve on what a machine can do. I'm more interested in finding out whether a computer / programme can do this kind of work for us in a way that is "reasonable" - I don't have any metric in mind for what "reasonable" means.

Comment: http://www.autobox.com/cms/

Comment: What does "general" mean in this context?  What (goodness) properties does the output have to satisfy in order to qualify? What if a human can apply expertise and do better for some time series than the completely automated solution? Etc.

Comment: Glen_b - the whole point is that it is general. I'm interested if anyone has completely automated the process of model building and forecasting in a way that works and allows a machine or programme do so without intervention. It's a good question so you shouldn't put it on hold. If someone has time to answer it, let them!

Comment: Mark L. Stone - I'm not so interested in whether a human can improve on what a machine can do. I'm more interested in finding out whether a computer / programme can do this kind of work for us in a way that is "reasonable" - I don't have any metric in mind for what "reasonable" means.

Comment: I'm voting to re-open this question because I think the generality is actually what makes it interesting. There's much that could be said specifically about the performance of algorithms over the set of all possible problems, the relevance of priors, etc. In general, I think the answer is: no, such a method is not possible

Comment: I don't think this question is too broad. The answer is definitely "no", although there are probably a lot of reasons why.

Comment: I think this is too broad, but if there are people who want to try to answer this, I'm inclined to let them.

Comment: “The consequences of our actions are always so complicated, so diverse, that predicting the future is a very difficult business indeed.”  (J.K. Rowling)

Comment: Various ["No Free Lunch" theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_free_lunch_theorem) may be of interest in this regard.

Comment: What about cortical sequence learning as proposed by Jeff Hawkin's "hierarchical temporal memory" models? They learn directly on streams of data by trying to mimic how the brain does it. Parameters needed are quite general as i understand it and can be set somewhat independently of the task. I don't know them well enough to write an answer though. https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.05463